# iOS multiple CALayers being added but only one gets applied

Tags: ios, swift, calayer

I want to add a left/right border to my textfield. It is an IBOutlet. Also if I also add the function to style the textfield inside of the didEdit delegate callback it will update correctly.

Here is my code.  Inside of ViewDidLoad.

```
let leftLayer = CALayer()
    leftLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: (password.frame.size.height - 1))
    leftLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor

    let rightLayer = CALayer()
    rightLayer.frame = CGRect(x: password.frame.size.width - 1, y: 0, width: 1, height: (password.frame.size.height - 1))
    rightLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor

    password.layer.setNeedsDisplay()
    password.layer.addSublayer(leftLayer)
    password.layer.display()

    password.layer.setNeedsDisplay()
    password.layer.addSublayer(rightLayer)
    password.layer.display()
```

I've taken out all code except

```
  let rightLayer = CALayer()
    rightLayer.frame = CGRect(x: password.frame.size.width - 1, y: 0, width: 1, height: (password.frame.size.height - 1))
    rightLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    password.layer.setNeedsDisplay()
    password.layer.addSublayer(rightLayer)
    password.layer.display()
```

But iOS simply will not add this layer. I tried the snippet below

```
var once = true
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    if once {
        styleTextViews()
        once = false
    }
}
```

The only thing that does work is if I call it from

```
 func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    styleTextViews()
}
```

Then it adds it just fine..

Comment: As the answer implies - check what the superview frame value is everyplace: `viewDidLoad` `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, etc. You'll learn quite a bit (I'm still learning). `viewDidLoad` is way too early. `viewWillLayoutSubviews` usually gets called multiple time. `viewDidLayoutSubviews` *may* get called more than once. Oh yeah, and `setNeedsDisplay`? Wrong. Let the OS do it's thing and *then* do your thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in `ViewDidLoad` you need to set this code inside `viewDidLayoutSubviews` because it contains the correct frame

```
var once  = true // as the function runs multiple times 

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
  super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
  if once {
   //  here 
    once = false
  }
}
```

Comment: Did not work. It's very strange whats happening. I've updated my snippet

Comment: can you use bounds instead of frame ??

Comment: Just adding it inside of viewDidLayoutSubviews and letting it be called a few times works. Not sure of downside